Nodemon: unable to run executable: "node"
I have installed nodemon on my pc, but while executing nodemon index.js command I am getting the following error: ( the code in file runs fine on node index.js command)

nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 3.1.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): .
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting node index.js
[nodemon] Error
at Bus.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\nodemon.js:162:25)
at Bus.emit (node:events:536:35)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:180:9)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:524:28)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:90:21)
[nodemon] unable to run executable: "node"

I tried :
1. reinstalling Nodemon(globally)
2. reinstalling Node
3. checking path of node and nodemon (both are correct)
4.  to run nodemon with explicit node path.
5. clearing npm cache.
6. npx nodemon index.js

Have you tried installing nodemon globally? Alternatively you can try npx nodemon index.js instead

yes, i have installed nodemon globally and tried npx nodemon index.js but the error  is still unresolved.
